# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propery“top” of null when used with dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I am getting the error "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property “top” of null" but only when used together with dialog.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
$.fx.speeds._default = 100000;
$(function() {
    $( ".mws-jui-dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: "true"
    });

    $( ".mws-dialog-pop" ).click(function() {
        $('.mws-jui-dialog[for="'+this.id+'"]').dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });     
});
</script>

<script>
$('#slider').sliderNav()
</script>
```

On its own sliderNav works great (and dialog works fine with sliderNav but not vice versa) but, I am using this for a directory application and each name is generated inside a loop which had a modal popup for each person with their details so I need to use them together.

The line the error points to in the slider js file is:

```
    var tOffset = $('.slider-content ' + target, slider).offset().top;
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, `$('.slider-content ' + target, slider)` is not matching any element.

Comment: Sorry I am rubbish at Javascript but it works fine without the dialog being present so surely it points to a conflict rather than something "wrong" with the code?